# How can I update Graphics.DrawLine() point positions?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, graphics, draw

I made a box that I drew using Graphics.DrawLine() for each edge. But I would like the box to be able to move around the screen freely, along with changing the size of the edges. The box is created by using a middle point and width and height, then basic math to find the 4 points which the lines connect to. My question is: How can I update the position of the lines? Do I have to clear the graphics and re-draw the lines each frame? Any answers will be helpful. Thank you.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point box_Middle = new Point(300, 300);

        int boxWidth = 100;
        int boxHeight = 200;

        Pen boxPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);

        DrawBox(e, boxPen, box_Middle, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }

    void DrawBox (PaintEventArgs e, Pen pen, Point middle, int width, int height)
    {
        graphics = e.Graphics;
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.
                                        Text.TextRenderingHint.
                                        SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;

        // Draw Box
        Point topLeft = new Point(middle.X - width / 2, middle.Y - height / 2);
        Point topRight = new Point(topLeft.X + width, topLeft.Y);
        Point bottomLeft = new Point(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y + height);
        Point bottomRight = new Point(topRight.X, bottomLeft.Y);

        graphics.DrawLine(pen, topLeft, topRight);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, topLeft, bottomLeft);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, bottomLeft, bottomRight);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, topRight, bottomRight);
    }
```

Comment: Add a `Timer` to update the variables, and call `Form1.Invalidate()`  to cause it to redraw.

Comment: _Do I have to clear the graphics and re-draw the lines each frame?_ Yes, that is necessary and just what Bradley recommends.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It works perfectly now.